# Vim substitute: Delete All between specified words

Tags: regex, vim, vi

A piece of the file I am trying to cut

```
HTMName=[...] owns the means of production. Proletariat do not and sell their labor power.
HTMFile=x
ClickPlay=0
TestElement=0

Type=HTML
Cors=123
DisplayAt=215
Hyperlink=0
HTMName=Bourgeois
HTMFile=x
ClickPlay=0
```

End result

```
[...] owns the means of production. Proletariat do not and sell their labor power.
Bourgeois
```

I am aware that the top and bottoms of the file will have remainders.
I have tried the following

```
:s%/^\sHTMFile[\s\S]*\n\s*HTMName=$//g
```

And many other variations which all return no pattern found. My grasp of regex is pretty weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I would delete all lines which don't contain the searched pattern (`HTMName=` at the start of the line), and then I would remove the searched pattern

```
:v/^HTMName=/d
:%s///
```

`:v` means execute a command (in this case ":d") on the lines  where {pattern} (in this case "HTMName=" at the start of the line) does NOT match.

`:d` means delete lines.

See more in help:

- [`:help :v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Av)
- [`:help :d`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#:d)

PS: If your pattern is not in just one line, you can try

```
:%s/^HTMName=\(\_.\{-}\)HTMFile=\|.*/\1/
```

Comment: v and d stands for?

Comment: `v` is a global command like `g` but it operates on the lines *not* matching the search pattern. In this case, for every line not starting with `HTMName=`, execute `d` *(=delete line)*

Comment: btw, you can shorten this to `v/^HTMName=/d|%s`